# Django admin field choices render as multiple checkbox

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to customise my Django admin page. I want a single model field to render all the choices passed to it as a CheckboxSelectMultiple, but can't get it to work.

Here is the relevant part of my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin

class Event(models.Model):
    GROUP_OWNER_CHOICES = (
            ('vcoe', "VCOE"),
            ('cssi', 'CSSI'),
            ('essc', "ESSC"),
            ('tmscc', "TMSCC"),
            ('inmc', "INMC"),
            ('ccs7', "CCS7"),
            ('ias', "IAS"),
        )

    group_owner = models.BooleanField(choices=GROUP_OWNER_CHOICES, blank=True, default=False)
```

I can't use the Django `formfield_overrides`(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) because I have more than 1 BooleanField and would like to keep the other BooleanField's intact.

Here is what I found from other questions

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Event
from django import forms

class EventGroupOwnerAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventGroupOwnerAdminForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields["group_owner"].widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EventGroupOwnerAdminForm

admin.site.register(Event , EventAdmin)
```

But the field simply doesnt render anything. Any help?

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to display 7 checkboxes, one for each choice. However, a `BooleanField` stores a single value, `True` or `False`. Therefore it does not make sense to pass those choices, or try to render it with that widget.

Comment: @Alasdair Ya thats exactly what I need, should I just have them individually and display them inline?